# Is it possible to set a desired capability (fullReset) for a single test out of many?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

For one test in the middle of my test suite I need to use fullReset to completely clear any data stored in an app.  I don't want to set fullReset as a desired capability for the entire test run as this will significantly slow it down.  After each test I tear down and restart the app.  Is it possible to only trigger a fullReset on one specific test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another class for full reset in the base package and extend that class wherever you want the test to use fullReset.